# CSS Transform Issues on Safari Mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

I have a small project where I implemented a card that rotates around the y-axis when a button it clicked. The card has a front and a backside. Seems like after iOS 16.4, something changed for Safari on mobile.

I added a touch event to the front and the back of the card. You can click anywhere on the front and the click event will log to the console. However, once you flip the card over, only half of the back is clickable.

I'm assuming it has to do with the origin of rotation since it's right down the middle.

Here is my example project:
https://playcode.io/1573169

Seems to be working perfectly fine on iOS 16.2. Any ideas on what exactly changed in Safari mobile?

I tried using -webkit and basically everything I could find. Seems to be an issue from 16.4

Edit: Happens on Chrome as well after iOS 16.4